# iOS: Adding UILabel to zoomed UIScrollview was blurred

Tags: iphone, ios

I am facing one strange issue when adding UILabel to zoomed UIScrollview problem.

I am adding two views to zoomed UIScrollview
1. UIImageView
2. UILabelView

Here the code am using to add UIImageView on UIScrollview

```
float recentZoomScaleValue = 4.5;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, y, 150, 150);

UIImageView *signatureImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];

[signatureImage setImage:image];
[signatureImage setFrame:rect];

//resize the frame to avoid the auto zoom
CGRect frame = signatureImage.frame;
frame.size.width /= recentZoomScaleValue;
frame.size.height /= recentZoomScaleValue;

[signatureImage setFrame:frame];

[self addSubView:signatureImage];
```

[self.scrollview addSubView:signatureImage];

Here the code am using to add UILabel on UIScrollview

```
float recentZoomScaleValue = 4.5;
txtLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, self.fontSize)];

[txtLabel setText:@"loganathan is a good boy"];

[txtLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:txtLabel.font.fontName size:self.fontSize]];

[txtLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[txtLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[txtLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

CGRect frame = signatureImage.frame;
frame.size.width /= recentZoomScaleValue;
frame.size.height /= recentZoomScaleValue;

[txtLabel setFrame:frame];
```

[self addSubview:txtLabel];

But the problem is when ever i tried to add UILabel view it added with auto zoomed. Since the label text was blurred. I do not know why and what is the problem. Shall i use CATextLayer instead of UILabel?. Any help that might be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the `contentsScale` to the right value when ever the zoomScale changes. Or initial to the current zoomScale:

Example for dynamic zooming:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    [yourLabel.layer setContentsScale:scale*[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
    [yourLabel.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: This will help us we already added uilabe to scrollview then user did zooming in/out?. But in my case after zoom operation done i am adding the label to scrollview on dynamic. Also when i add uiview and uiimageview it was working fine. But when i add label, button or slider it's added to scrollview with auto zoomed. Since it shows like  blurred view on top of scrollview.

Comment: you should also be able to this with newly added views. Try adding the lines `[txtLabel.layer setContentsScale:scale*[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]]` and `[txtLabel.layer setNeedsDisplay]` to your code.

Comment: I tried this but it was not working. One way is there to solve it. We need to find out the label width dynamically based on number of characters in the text and font size of the text. If we achieve this then i can convert that uilabel to uiimage then i can re-use the same uiimageview code. This is good idea?. Because while adding image to scrollview i know the actual size so i set the frame to that imageview. But while adding uilabel i do now know the exact frame size because it will increase or decrease based on font size and also the language english or german or arabic.

Comment: finally i used draw rect method to draw the string into the rect and clipped that rect as an image and then everything works fine. but this is not a perfect solution.